# Object reference of current ribbon in excel

Tags: c#, office-interop, excel-interop

I have 4 buttons in my excel ribbon. Once I click on the 4th button I want to hide the visibility of the other 3 buttons. How can I do that in c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple. Its in tree node structure. Found out how to do it.